# Using serial to usb driver on raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, raspberry-pi

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3.  The USB ports seem to work fine for other uses, but a serial-to-usb cable does not seems to work.  I have been using the cable and a program that reads from the port on x86_64 CentOS 6 just fine.  When I plug it in /dev/ttyUSB0 gets created (just as with CentOS), my code is able to open() the device but read() never returns any characters.  Any idea why it fails?  I use open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY ) which succeeds but read(fd,&c,1) never returns.

Comment: May be a power problem, if the Pi is not delivering enough power to the adaptor.

Comment: Why not to use embedded serial port `/dev/ttyAMA0` on pins 8 & 10?

Comment: I am actually using a GPS dongle that has a Prolific serial to usb built in.  Also other serial to usb cables appear to have the same problem (most use the same Prolific chip).

Comment: RP3 uses a 2A power supply to generout supply power and I am not using any of the other USB ports.  I even tried a Y-cable that draws power from two ports with the same results.

Comment: So essentially you're complaining that your program doesn't work.  But you haven't posted any code.  Just because the program *"works"* on one machine doesn't mean that you have portable code and it should work elsewhere.  Therefore all you have done is start a guessing game.  The syslog for the USB adapter would also be salient.  @richard -- A USB-to-serial adapter draws less then 10 mA (I've measured it).

Comment: If it would be me, I would try first to establish communication with GPS over USB unit with help of `minicom`

Comment: I did try minicom and it also shows no input on RaspberryPi3 but shows it fine on CentOS on an x86_64.  I was just wondering if anyone else has successfully used a serial-to-usb adapter on a RaspberryPi3.

Comment: I am sorry.  minicom DOES work, so the fault is in my program not the driver - some difference between CentOS 6 and Ubuntu in setting up the port evidently.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is some issue with my own code.  I tried minicom and when serial options are set correctly it DOES read the ttyUSB0 port and my GPS dongle can be read fine.  There is apparently some difference in serial port setup between CentOS and Ubuntu that I need to find.  Thanks for those who commented.